# Best-First search in Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am starting to work with boost graph library. I need a best-first search, which I could implement using astar_search by having zero costs. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

However, I wonder if there is another possibility of doing this? If the costs are not considered, the algorithm should be slightly more efficient.

EDIT: Sorry for the unclear description. I am actually implementing a potential field search, so I don't have any costs/weights associated with the edges but rather need to do a steepest-descent-search (which can overcome local minima).

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: lol i suppose you mean breadth-first search?

Comment: @wilhelmtell: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely use A* to tackle this; you'd need **h(x)** to be 0 though, not **g(x)**. A* rates nodes based on F which is defined by

```
F(n) = g(n) + h(n).

TotalCost = PathCost + Heuristic.
```

> g(n) = Path cost, the distance from the initial to the current state
>
> h(n) = Heuristic, the estimation of cost from current state to end state.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a):

> Dijkstra's algorithm, as another
>   example of a best-first search
>   algorithm, can be viewed as a special
>   case of A* where h(x) = 0 for all x.

Comment: sorry if I didn't express clearly what I am looking for, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with C++, I would suggest trying out [YAGSBPL](http://code.google.com/p/yagsbpl/).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Aphex's answer, you might want to use Dijkstra's algorithm; one way to set the edge weights is to set `w(u, v)` to `potential(v) - potential(u)`, assuming that is nonnegative.  Dijkstra's algorithm assumes that edge weights are positive and so that distances increase as you move away from the source node.  If you are searching for the smallest potential, flip the sides of the subtraction; if you have potentials that go both up and down you might need to use something like Bellman-Ford which is not best-first.